# How to set up SVN credentials in Jenkins?

Tags: svn, version-control, continuous-integration, jenkins

Is there a way to set up credentials that will be used by Jenkins when it performs SVN commit? I could't find a way to do so.

If I run Jenkins server on my machine, which has SVN client installed and my credentials are cached, it seems to work fine, but if I try to run Jenkins server on another machine, then I get an error.
`ERROR: Failed to tag
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNCancelException: svn: No credential to try. Authentication failed`

Comment: How do you connect to your server from the command line? I mean, do you use `svn+ssh://` or something else?

Comment: +1 I didn't realize Jenkins preferred (or even read) the local credentials on disk over what's defined in `hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.xml`.

Answer (score 46):

If you go to the job configuration window where Jenkins asks for the repositories; if you wait a second after you put in the repo it tries to connect, if its unable to connect it prompts you with red text under the repository location[shown below]; click the provided link you are able to provide a key and any other way you would like to authenticate. It will then try to connect if it's successful your build should connect fine. 
[image]

The url to setup authentication for the other machine would be here through jenkins if you can't get red prompt to come up.

Comment: Also, if you click on the help question mark button next to the repo url, the explanation within has a link to reset credentials. Not very intuitive but works.

Comment: I don't see any of these links in my case. Not sure what's wrong with my install it used to work before. All I see is "/trunk doesn't exist in the repository".

Comment: In case you are having trouble finding it, the URL is `http://jenkins.mycompany.com/scm/SubversionSCM/enterCredential`.

Comment: I know this is old but did you realize you blacked out the URL but it still appears in the error message?  Gave me a laugh.

Comment: But how will it help to commit ?

Answer (score 18):

If it still doesn't work there is a way for you to manually enter your credentials.

Next to the Repository URL text box click the question mark. In that box will be the following text: "click this link and specify different credential". Click on that link to open the Subversion Authentication page. On that page enter the root of the repository URL, enter the login and password to use and click OK.

Answer (score 2):

We use `svn+ssh` for our authentication mechanism and in our case, you have to make sure your slave has ssh access that does not require manual password entry (i.e. use `ssh-keygen` to generate a key).

If you can ssh into the server simply by doing `ssh username@server`, then Jenkins should not have a problem performing commits.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a checkout operations on the Jenkins server command line (on master or slave), and enter user and pass there, accept the SSL certificate permanently, and then you do not need credentials for SVN commands in your Job configuration.