# How to get Jenkins to commit changes to SVN when username and password is required

Tags: svn, jenkins, continuous-integration

Jenkins has a username & password stored for use with the SVN plugin - they are used to extract the code for building (this works perfectly fine).

I now want to commit some files to SVN after a successful build in Jenkins.

How can this be achieved?

I tried the following as part of a 'windows batch command', but obviously it requires a username & password how can I get it to pass the username & password already configured in Jenkins?

```
svn add "%WORKSPACE%\References\XXXX\XXX 2.0 Container\*.*"
svn commit "%WORKSPACE%\References\XXXX\XXX 2.0 Container"
```

Comment: Perhaps this could help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301314/how-to-set-up-svn-credentials-in-jenkins