# Jenkins Blue Ocean Provide Credentials for Subversion SCM Step

Tags: jenkins, svn, credentials, jenkins-blueocean

I set up a Jenkins(all recommented plugins) on a plain WIN10-VM to test if the Blue Ocean plugin is an option for me and my colleagues to simply build setups. In Addition I set up a local Git-Server (Bonobo) to store the Jenkinsfile for BlueOcean (SVN is actually not supported).

I created a new pipeline in Blue Ocean. As one of the first step I wanted to checkout the source via subversion. I created a subversion step and filled in the url of the repository and checked the poll option. Now I need to provide the credentials for the svn-repro but I dont know how to do it.

Is it even possible to use the svn-plugin in BlueOcean or is the only way to use a script to checkout from svn in BlueOcean?

What I tried so far:

1. Accepting https-Certificate as SYSTEM in SYSTEM-CMD
2. Added the SVN-Credentials to the Jenkins/Pipeline
3. Tried to set the credentials as suggested in ([How to set up SVN credentials in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301314/how-to-set-up-svn-credentials-in-jenkins))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself after getting some hints and tipps from several sites:

1. Generate a Code Snippet for "Check out from Source Control" as discribed here:([Checkout SVN with credentials in Jenkins pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36881132/checkout-svn-with-credentials-in-jenkins-pipeline))
2. Go to the Pipeline Editor and press [Strg]+[s] to open the "Pipeline Script" Window
3. Create a new Stage and fill in the Steps with the code snippet:

```
stage('Checkout with SVN'){
     steps {
      ***Paste here the code snippet from the generator (Step 1)***
     }
    }
```

4. Be happy to get the checkout :)
   Greetings,
   bluescreenterror